# Understanding why a Java pattern matches incorrect text inside buffered .java file?

Tags: java, regex, buffer

Full disclosure: still very new to Java.

I'm contributing to the open source [xmage project](https://github.com/magefree/mage) and we agreed to remove the copyright header text from all files in the project in favour of a single LICENSE.txt file inside the project root.

Due to the limitations of my IDE recognising regex patterns across multiple files I decided to write a script. Here's the script:

**Note:** *updated and working script* (won't overwrite hidden files or symbolic links)

```
/*
  Remove the copy right header from all files inside project.
*/
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RemoveHeaders {

  private static String readEntireFile(String filePath) {
    String content = "";

    try {
      content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content;
  }

  private static void saveFileToDisk(String filePath, String content) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
      if (Files.isWritable(path) && !Files.isSymbolicLink(path) && !Files.isHidden(path)) {
        writer.write(content);
        writer.flush();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static String removeMatchingText(String content, Pattern pattern) {
    return pattern.matcher(content).replaceAll("");
  }

  public static void recursivelyGetFilesAndRemoveHeaders(String path) {
    Pattern copyrightHeader = Pattern.compile("(?i)/\\*(?:\r?\n|\r) ?\\*.*?Copyright[\\S\\s]*?\\*/");
    File currentDirectory = new File(path);
    File[] files = currentDirectory.listFiles();

    if (files == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (File file : files) {
      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        recursivelyGetFilesAndRemoveHeaders(file.getAbsolutePath());
      } else {
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        String fileContents = readEntireFile(filePath);
        String updatedContents = removeMatchingText(fileContents, copyrightHeader);
        if (fileContents != updatedContents) {
          saveFileToDisk(filePath, updatedContents);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    recursivelyGetFilesAndRemoveHeaders(rootPath);
  }
}
```

For clarity and easy reference this is the (updated) regex being used:

`"(?i)/\\*(?:\r?\n|\r) ?\\*.*?Copyright[\\S\\s]*?\\*/"`

Here is where things get weird: I tested the pattern on [this file](https://github.com/magefree/mage/blob/master/Mage.Client/src/main/java/mage/client/MageFrame.java) and to my surprise, not only was the copyright header comment removed, but the pattern matched [line 1428](https://github.com/magefree/mage/blob/remove-license-headers/Mage.Client/src/main/java/mage/client/MageFrame.java#L1428) and removed everything up until [line 1554](https://github.com/magefree/mage/blob/remove-license-headers/Mage.Client/src/main/java/mage/client/MageFrame.java#L1554).

I thought it might be a buffering problem and so rewrote the readEntireFile function using FileInputStream, making sure to close the stream before returning the result of reading the file - but this produced the same result.

My thinking now is that it is some quirk of the regex handler in Java? Using the exact same pattern in [JavaScript on the same file](https://regexr.com/3qbma) results in the expected match (only the copyright header).

Just in case here's the system and java details:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Thanks for taking the time to read through this - been working on this all day and am totally stuck and a little confused. Cheers!

Comment: Your file line endings may be CRLF. Replace `\n` with `\\R`.

Comment: Unfortunately the exact same problem if using `\\R` - but a nice thought!

Comment: Are there more whitespaces? Try `"/\\*[\\s*]*Copyright[\\S\\s]*?\\*/"`. Also, are the whitespaces ASCII or any Unicode ones? Try `"(?Us)/\\*[\\s*]*Copyright.*?\\*/"`.

Comment: Why  don't you post the regex you're using instead of making people click all your links to find it ?? If you have an old-school comment  /**/ at the top of the file only, this is specific. It is easy to do `(?is)^\s*/\*\s*copyright.*?\*/\s*`. Otherwise, the problems mount up if it's anywhere else. It may be hidden inside quotes, comment syntax may be hidden inside line comment syntax //. That is doable, but you have to be specific. Also, never use just `\n` as this is not correct, use this instead `(?:\r?\n|\r)`

Comment: Hi sln - sorry the regex was a bit hidden in the original post - also next time I will link to the files but also copy the relevant parts. Duly noted :) Just to clarify - is the capture group in your example also necessary or would `?:\r?\n|\r` suffice?

Comment: @GrayedFox - All regex engine syntax use a general grouping construct `()` to denote the action applies to it's contents. The _Action_ is specified by specific character(s) immediately following the opening parenthesis. Some possibilities are `(?:)` cluster group; `()` capture group; `(?=)` assertion; `(?>)` atomic; `(?ism)` modifier; `(?&)` function call; `(?'xx')` named capture;  `(?{xx})` code; , etc ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to flush the output.

Adding this in the `saveFileToDisk` method will do:

```
writer = new FileWriter(file);
writer.write(content);
writer.flush();
```

(For me, it did not remove the Copyright header, but at least the rest of the removal was omitted. However, the former might be related to the one of the reasons, Wiktor already mentioned in his/her comments.)

Thus, since java 7, use of the try-with-resources statement is encouraged:

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    writer.write(content);
}
```

This statement will automatically close the `FileWriter`, which implies flushing.

---

For explanation:

Streaming output in java (both `OutputStream` and `Writer`) is - in concept - buffered. This means that every implementation class is allowed to buffer the throughput internally without explicitly documenting it.

All `write` methods do therefore not necessarily write to the underlying resources immediately. However, both base classes offer a `flush` method that does exactly that: it flushes the internal buffer to the underlying resource.

Comment: This fixed it -- also glad to know my hunch about it being something to do with the buffer wasn't too far off the mark! Thank you!